# Parcelable Class with list of a custom objects

Tags: android, inner-classes, parcelable

I have a Custom object that have an inner class, And the whole item needs to be Parcelable,

```
public class FechasReservasZonas implements Parcelable {

public String hora;
public List<Zona> listaZonas;


public FechasReservasZonas(){};
public FechasReservasZonas(Parcel in){readFromParcel(in);};
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(hora);
        dest.writeList(listaZonas);
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in){
    hora = in.readString();
    in.readList(listaZonas,Zona.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public FechasReservasZonas createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FechasReservasZonas(in);
    }

    public FechasReservasZonas[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FechasReservasZonas[size];
    }
};


public class Zona implements Serializable{

    public int IDZona;
    public String NombreZona;

}
```

}

It doesnt give any error, but when I try to put is as a ParcelableArray it gives me an error

```
 public static ReservasCuadranteFragment newInstance(ArrayList<FechasReservasZonas> fechas,String nombre) {
    ReservasCuadranteFragment fragment = new ReservasCuadranteFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    // THIS LINE GIVE ERROR
    args.putParcelableArray(ARG_PARAM1, fechas);


    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, nombre);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

error:

```
Error:(49, 45) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<FechasReservasZonas> cannot be converted to Parcelable[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because `fechas` is an ArrayList and not an Array of `FechasReservasZonas`. In this case you should be using

`putParcelableArrayList` instead of `putParcelableArray`

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) you can find the documentation

Comment: OMG Copy paste errors... Thanks I didnt even notice it!, I will accept answer